# Outlook REST API 2 Mark Message as Junk / Spam

Tags: c#, rest, email, outlook, outlook-restapi

I've tried Googling it, but to no avail, so I am here asking for solution to this (seemingly) straightforward question: **How do you mark a message as 'Junk' using Outlook REST API 2.0** ? Currently, the [API documentation link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) does not provide any help in this, only thing I could do is as follows, which basically "moves" a message from Inbox to Junk Email, not really ideal.

```
 string strID = lstFolders.Where(s => s.DisplayName == "Junk E-Mail").Select(s => s.Id).SingleOrDefault();

                try
                {
                    // Try to get message and move to junk.
                    Message junkMessage = (Message)await client.Me.Messages.GetById(req.MessageID).ExecuteAsync();

                    await junkMessage.MoveAsync(strID);

                    return request.GetOKResponseJSON(new
                    {
                        SuccessMessage = string.Format("MessageID: {0} <br /> from UserEmail: '{1}' Moved to Junk", req.MessageID, req.UserEmail)
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        string.Format("MessageID: {0} <br /> from UserEmail: '{1}' FAILED to be Moved to Junk due to error: ",
                        req.MessageID, req.UserEmail, ex));
                }
```

As you can see, my message is merely *moved* to Junk, I think this however, does **not** prevent same messages coming back into Inbox, instead of going straight to Junk folder.

Any help in this would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: well if their api is anything like their UI they have willfully crippled it in some way.  Until the most recent change you could easily block all senders in a domain, then after a lot of design work they changed it to be much more difficult just like regular Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the REST API doesn't support marking a message as Junk. This would be a good feature to suggest on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com) though!

Comment: Not via REST. EWS has some ability here though. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn481311(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thank you but I know about it, our set up is on REST API, so unless I can use same token received in my API from user, to use EWS methods, this approach isn't useful. Can you please suggest if EWS can allow this? The uservoice feature request [link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16798954-outlook-rest-api-2-mark-message-as-junk-spam) created.

Comment: Anyone wants to help?